# Connect to ThinkOrSwim using NDDE in .Net

Tags: .net, dde

I am successfully receiving DDE data from the ThinkOrSwim trading platform into excel using this cell formula:

```
=TOS|Last!AAPL
```

However, when I try to connect to ThinkOrSwim DDE using the [NDDE library](http://ndde.codeplex.com/) in a .Net C# application, I receive the following error message, which is the same as I would get if the ThinkOrSwim platform was not running at all:

*The client failed to connect to "TOS|LAST".  Make sure the server application is running and that it supports the specified service name and topic name pair.*

The exact same method of connecting with NDDE worked in 2009, and failed when I re-utilised it in 2012. Perhaps ThinkOrSwim have made some change in their application to block it? I'm wondering what to do next ... either find a way to make NDDE work (better), or run an excel spreadsheet inside my .Net application (messy).

Hoping someone here knows I way I can continue using NDDE and fix that connection problem.

[Click to download small code library I created to demonstrate this problem (Visual Studio 2010)](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2-rHH8gGTDUeHJ4aGxueWVGamM). You will have to click File->Download after the page loads.

Bounty is only for answers showing a solution that uses a pure .Net / windows api solution. Automating excel within .Net is not accepted for the bounty.

Download ThinkOrSwim from: https://mediaserver.thinkorswim.com/installer/InstFiles/thinkorswim_jse6_installer.exe
Contact me privately if you need to for login details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution: I had to run Visual Studio as administrator to get it to work in debug. To make the .exe work, I had to add an app.manifest file with the following:

```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
     <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
```

Answer (score 3):

Right Click on thinkorswim.exe , go to the compatibility tab

> check the "Run as Administrator" box at the bottom.
>
> Click Apply.

Comment: Thanks Charvind, this was pretty close to the answer I needed. See mine below.